# An equality from the well-known analysis of variance formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have a parametric model $(\mathcal{Y},\{P_\theta:\theta\in\Theta\})$ dominated by some measure $\mu$. That is, each $\theta$ is associated with a density $l(y;\theta)$. Let $S(Y)$ denote a statistic. The book I'm reading claims that follow equality:
$$
\text{Var}_\theta\left(\frac{\partial\log l(Y;\theta)}{\partial\theta}\right)=E_\theta\text{Var}_\theta\left(\frac{\partial\log l(Y;\theta)}{\partial\theta}\bigg|S(Y)\right)+\text{Var}_\theta E_\theta\left(\frac{\partial\log(Y;\theta)}{\partial\theta}\bigg|S(Y)\right)\quad\tag{*}
$$
follows from the well-known analysis of variance formula. Can you please indicate which formula it is and how does one prove (*)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance

Comment: @d.k.o. Hello, if you turn that comment into an answer (perhaps with a bit more details), I'll very gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*) is an application of the **law of total variance**

$$Var(X)=\mathbb{E}[Var(X|Y)]+Var(\mathbb{E}[X|Y])\text{ (1)}$$

It follows for the tower property of conditional expectation: $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]]$, conditional variance formula: $Var(X|Y)=\mathbb{E}[X^2|Y]-(\mathbb{E}[X|Y])^2$, and the fact the conditional expectation is a random variable:

$$Var(X)=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X^2|Y]]-(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]])^2=$$
$$=\mathbb{E}[Var(X|Y)]+\mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[X|Y])^2]-(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]])^2=\text{(1)}$$